# Position absolute doesn't work correctly in Chrome when is contained in a relative span

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a problem related to Chrome Browser.
My html contains a lot of span tags, some spans have the **position: relative** css property because it contains a div with **position: absolute**.The div have to be on the bottom-left of the span.

It works fine, but when the span starts in a new line there is a problem: the **div.arrow** is positioned in a wrong way (look images and code). (if you prefer: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4hLowyc/2/))

```css
.selected {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.arrow {
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 0 solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-width: 4px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span class="selected"><div class="arrow"></div>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span>
```

To reproduce the issue, you have to resize your window like the attached image:
[image]

The expected behaviour should be:
[image]

Do you have any ideas to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a background instead to avoid the issue of `position:absolute` and you won't need any extra element or pseudo element. Note that `div` inside `span` is invalid

```css
.selected {
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  background:
    /* The arrow*/
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49.5%,red 50%) bottom 2px left 0/4px 4px,
    /* The line*/
    linear-gradient(red,red) bottom/100% 2px,
    /* Backgroudn color */
    lightblue;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span class="selected">foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span> <span>foobar</span>
```

Comment: Maybe this can be a solution if i can also set a background-color to the rest of the span. For example: red color for arrow and underline and blue for the rest. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `display: inline-block;` to your `.selected` class.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.